# sql - select data from 2 tables

Tags: php, sql

I have 2 tables - chats_topices and chats_replies

I would like to select all chats_topices fields + the field createDate (timestamp) from chats_replies which closest to the current date.

chats_replies contain field CHATID that connect between the tables

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM `chats_topics` AS topics, `chats_replies` AS replies
        WHERE (".$search.") AND
                (topics.id = replies.chatID) AND
                (XXXX)
        ORDER BY topics.createDate DESC";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's bad practice to use SELECT * in live code, I'd go with something like this;

```
SELECT topics.Field1, topics.Field2, MAX(replies.createDate) createDate
FROM `chats_topics` AS topics
LEFT JOIN `chats_replies` AS replies
ON topics.id = replies.chatID
WHERE (".$search.")
    AND (topics.id = replies.chatID)
    AND (XXXX)
GROUP BY topics.Field1, topics.Field2
ORDER BY topics.createDate DESC
```

Add in your fields that you need to the select and also add them in the group by.

Comment: thank you. 1 thing - if i have 2 replies to the same chat i get it twice in results...

Comment: that shouldn't happen unless there's duplicate data in chats_topics. You're definitely using the MAX with a GROUP BY?

Answer (score 1):

Rich Benner gave you a good join statement for this particular problem. I would like to follow up and attach an image I have found useful when making join statements in the hopes that it might help in the future. I don't remember where I got this picture (although you can see a copyright on the bottom).

[image]